# modules for muliple service account in different projects in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-modules

I have my current TF code setup like this.

```html
../../modules/cp_project
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_binding" "bucket_permission" {
  bucket = google_container_registry.registry.id
  role   = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
  members = var.members
}

qat01.tf
module "qat01_project" {
  source = "../../../../modules/cp_project"
 members = [
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c001@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c002@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c001@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c002@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infra-c001@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infras-c002@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
  }
  
dev01.tf
module "dev01_project" {
  source = "../../../../modules/cp_project"
  members= [
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c001@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c002@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c003@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c004@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infra-c003@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infras-c004@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
  }
```

The service accounts varies for project to project as you see in the code. Is there any efficient(logical) way I add the service accounts in modules/cp_project itself. I do have multiple files like prod.tf and preprod.tf which uses the same module with the different email addresses in members. I want to put all the these project specific members in modules/cp_project and then the respective projects can call the respective members list from cp_project itself. Is there a way? Thank You

[image: File structure]

As you see from the file structure, I want to list the service account members in module/vars.tf and call the variables from qat01 or dev01.
So i want the module/vars.tf look like the following. And the variables can be called by dev01.tf and qat01.tf in "members" variable. Example of how module/vars.tf looks as follows

```html
 module/vars.tf

variable "qat01_members" {
    type= list(any)
    default = [
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c001@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c002@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c001@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c002@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infra-c001@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infras-c002@qat01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ] 
}

variable "dev01_members" {
    type= list(any)
    default = [
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c001@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-default-c002@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c003@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-ecp-c004@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infra-c003@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:k8s-infras-c004@dev01.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    ]  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking if there's a way to *create* the service account inside the `cp_project` module?

Comment: yes. but service account list varies for project too. as you see in qat01.tf and dev01.tf

Comment: You can create a map with keys as dev,qat,prod with values as service account list.

Comment: How Can i refer them in the dev01.tf or qat01.tf though?

Comment: Still not quite following. Maybe you can show some pseudocode that demonstrates what you *want* to be able to do, and we can show you how to achieve it.

Comment: It seems that you are asking about writing reusable modules, for example as in https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d